# html css - full size image and view can be zoomed

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, zooming

I would like to have a html css solution for a website with only one picture . I have the following         requirements:

1. If you open the website with any browser, then the width of the
   picture = the width of browser window
2. You can zoom in the picture

I have solution where I get the size of the browser window by a js by using window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio see [Link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-detect-screen-resolution-with-javascript.php), but it dosen't work for all devices. If I'am using something like that, I can not zoom in:

```html
<img style="width:100%;" src="https://images8.alphacoders.com/712/712496.jpg">
```

Is there a css solution or a js solution without getting the width in pixels that works for all devices and browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the checkbox type input to see whether the user has clicked or not. When the user clicks, the checkbox goes into checked state and hence we can use the following pure CSS solution. The unit of width used here is 'vw' (means viewport-width) which is basically the width of the client viewing window.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

img{
  width: 100vw;
}

.toggle{
  position: fixed;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
     
.toggle:checked+img{
  width: 200vw;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox class="toggle">
<img src="https://images8.alphacoders.com/712/712496.jpg">
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there also a solution, where I can zoom in with ctrl +?

Comment: @leisinger ctrl + is used to zoom into your browser since it is an accessibility option. There are ways in javascript to do it but since CSS is only a style sheet and not a command processing tool, I have not come across any method to do that. What you can possibly do is to open your image in a new window on clicking the image by surrounding it in an <a> tag and link to the image location. Then you can use the Ctrl + option to zoom in. Hope that helps :)